# Rendering a texture with alpha test and blend it with a color and the scene behind

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha, alphablending, blending

I would like to render this image (alpha = 0 on white)

[image]

On a square (actually a quad strip, but it doesnt matter I guess) blending it with a color, the blending should be performed on the whole surface, that is also where the texture has alpha equals zero.

Then the result should be blended on turn on the scene

How can I achieve that?

I dont want obviously all the code, just the key piece, like the blend function (I suppose)

Comment: Too much use of the word "blend". What exactly do you mean by it? Can you describe the visual effect you want (preferably without the word "blend")? Can you write out a mathematical equation?

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry for the delay, but I was busy with other stuff. However what I mean is (without the blend word :p) : Render the above texture on a surface, let's say a square, applying also a color background (this should be easily accomplished by a gl.glColor) like this one [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png). Last thing: the world behind should still be visible with a specific alpha value. I am sorry if I didnt make clear enough before, let me know if it is ok now :)

Comment: Do you mean alpha blending ? Do you use hardware blending functions  here?